# Method not found: 'Void EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to scaffold and getting following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator Method not found: 'Void EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations

Comment: also provide  your start.cs code related to the configuration of Sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db?view=aspnetcore-2.0#install-entity-framework

I suspect you are missing the assemblies that are necessary for scaffolding?  I also assume you are trying to reverse engineer an existing db?

example
`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

if it fails like i can't find it might be a pmc issue, try closing down VS try again.  After that its probably a configuration with missing assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

It may  be the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` version issue. Update it to version 2.0.3. It worked for me.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: 2020 UPDATE: I got this error runing version 5.0.1 and it worked with version 3.1.10 :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too when trying to add a new controller. The day before I had upgraded both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` Nuget Packages from version `2.0.2` to `2.1.3`.

Downgrading both packages to `2.0.2` allowed me to scaffold a new controller again.

Answer (score 0):

Saeef's error is from trying to create CRUD razor pages, not creating the domain classes from an existing database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had two instances of VS2017 (enterprise & developer edition) for some reason I updated only one of them. The shourtcut on my desk was the 'out of date version' so I didnt figure it out until now.
I uninstalled the older, updated the other to 15.8+ and it works fine now.

Comment: It is good that you are helping people to solve the problem. But are you sure that this will fix the problem? If you are not sure or if you are suggesting something to people, you can write it in comment section. :)