# Error: There was an error runnig the selected code generator: 'Method not found...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I working on my small `.NET Core` 2.0 `MVC` Project. What i want to do is to generate read/write controller with views but when it scafolding, i have an error:

[image]
[image]

I'm using:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v2.0.8
- EFCore                   v2.2.0
- EFCore.SqlServer         v2.2.0
- EfCore.Tools             v2.2.0
- Microsoft.NETCore.App    v2.0.0
- Microsoft.VS.Web.Code.Generation.Design v2.0.4
- Npgsql.Entity.Framework.Core.postgreSQL v.2.1.2 (my friend that i work with have local db set up in Postgre)

My database is set up corectly on LocalDB.

**FarmDbContext.cs**

```
namespace Farm.Models
{
public class FarmDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FarmDbContext(DbContextOptions<FarmDbContext>
        options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Farm>         Farms          { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Animal>       Animals        { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cultivation>  Cultivations   { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dairy>        Dairies        { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grain>        Grains         { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Machine>      Machines       { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MilkQuantity> MilkQuantities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Silo>         Silos          { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Species>      Species        { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker>       Workers        { get; set; }
}
}
```

Part of **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<FarmDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

For example, my **Farm.cs** Model:

```
namespace Farm.Models
{
public class Farm
{
    [Key]
    public int    Id                      { get; set; }
    public string Localization            { get; set; }

    public List<Animal>      Animals      { get; set; }
    public List<Worker>      Workers      { get; set; }
    public List<Machine>     Machines     { get; set; }
    public List<Silo>        Silos        { get; set; }
    public List<Cultivation> Cultivations { get; set; }
}
}
```

When i want to just generate `View` automatically (for example, `Create`) from any model, i get the same error. How to repair that?

**EDIT:**

When i upgraded `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` to ver 2.2.0, scafolding works longer than before and i get this error:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Method not found: 'Void EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645265/method-not-found-void-entityframeworkcore-design-internal-dbcontextoperations)

Comment: Of course i see that, but closing and opening VS 2017 again not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

- Upgraded VIsual Studio 2017 to ver. 15.9.3 (i had 15.7)
- Downgrade NETCore.App and AspNetCore.ALL to ver 2.1
- Change project target to Net Core 2.1

Now, generating controllers with views works perfectly